# php require() weird conflict

Tags: php, path

Okay.
I have this big folder WEBSITE
in it I have `classes` folder , `includes` folder and a `index.php` file

->->

In the includes folder I have a `config.php` . This file is being required by index.php(from the main folder) like this:

```
require('includes/config.php');
```

In config.php I also have this:

```
 include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
```

The thing is when I open index.php , everything works.But if I open includes/config.php I'm getting the `No such file or directory` error that is obvious because normally  , my path should be

`include('../classes/user.php');
    include('../classes/phpmailer/mail.php');`

but that would end up in my index.php file not working by telling me the two includes above can't be found.

Is there a proper way in achieving what I want ?

Thank you.

Comment: show your directory sructure

Comment: The path to the incuded file is based on the file in which you are including that file.

Comment: @AmitGaud Read my first sentence of the questions. Thats the structure of the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths when including files:

```
 include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/classes/user.php");
```

or

```
 include(__DIR__ . "/../classes/user.php");
```